# Sum of Column in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to get the sum of a column using PHP.

However this is my output:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [OrderPrice] => 5.99 ) )
>   Price: 0

Can someone please explain why I am not getting the sum, which should be 5.99 as shown above.

Comment: array_sum() sums up the values from an array.  Here you have an array of arrays, so it tries to do `$orderArr[0] + nothing`.  To get the sum of all values you need to sum `$orderArr[0][OrderPrice] + $orderArr[1][OrderPrice] + ...`

Comment: Because you have a nested array. https://3v4l.org/nYGF4 - see what @NigelRen and TimBiegeleisen said anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a direct answer/solution to your immediate PHP problem, which some guru might address, but if you want to sum a SQL column, you would probably be better off doing this in SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(OrderPrice) AS order_price_sum FROM PizzaOrder
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have an array of arrays, you need to sum up the `OrderPrice` elements of each sub array.  So in PHP you would extract this column using `array_column()` and add this array instead...

```
echo array_sum(array_column($orderArr, 'OrderPrice'));
```

BUT, you should do this in MySQL, unless you also need the data for other purposes.

Answer (score -1):

why you just edit your sql statement to get the sum

```
SELECT SUM(OrderPrice) FROM PizzaOrder
```

if you need the all values `SELECT OrderPrice,SUM(OrderPrice) FROM PizzaOrder`

and you can get the sum from the whole column.